# Refreshing UIViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Ok in my app i have a uiviewcontroller for the current user profile and a tableview. When the user clicks a table view cell that contains the current users followers, i refresh the view controller with the new user profile.  When i add my code in the viewDidLoad everytime i hit back in the navigation bar it goes back to the last user but when i keep clicking a table view cell the app gets a memory warning and crashes.  Now i tried in the viewDidAppear and doing this didnt get no crashes or memory warnings but when i hit back it goes back to the current user

Here is how i set up my code in

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        userTableView.delegate = self
        userTableView.dataSource = self
        let query = PFUser.query()
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: ChartsViewController.otherUser.user)
        query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil || object == nil {
                println("The getFirstObject request failed.")
          } else {
                //The find succeeded.
                self.userProfile = object as PFUser!
             }
    }
```

And my code when the table view cell is clicked

```
ChartsViewController.otherUser.user = object["username"] as String

                self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OtherUserProfileViewController") as UIViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: You need to respond to the tableView delegate method "didSelectCellAtIndexPath:", update your array, and have a separate function to call.

ViewDidAppear is called once, when your view appears (and most things are loaded). It is not meant to be called again.

I don't know what to recommend at this point, other than Python the Hard Way or a similar book to get the structure of things.

Comment: @Stephen J if u wouldnt mind me asking how can i stop the app from crashing when i add it to viewDidLoad? I think its crashing because of to many view controllers?

Comment: No, you can have as many as you want. It's because ViewDidLoad is only when your view loaded, but the tableView and such isn't loaded and you're accessing/moving nil variables. You need to read and understand the TableView programming guide, Views Programming guide, and Views and View Controllers guide. They tell you when stuff will happen and why, and how to know when Lazy Loading occurs.
Basic functions and debugging skills, plus proper structure helps.
Stanford has a lecture on iPhone programming that shows using tableView